# How to run a python script in django server using a button

Tags: python, django, triggers

I want to run my script (makes changes to my database and creates users on another website using an API) whenever a user presses the button on my website. So far i have tried these solutions but they are not working for me.

[How can i trigger a Python script in background from HTML tag button, in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119785/how-can-i-trigger-a-python-script-in-background-from-html-tag-button-in-django)

[Run python script in Django website when clicking on button submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519578/run-python-script-in-django-website-when-clicking-on-button-submit)

The view

```
def external(request):
    out = run([sys.executable, 'C:\\Users\\hafiz\\PycharmProjects\\DotsPrototype\\proto\\moodle.py'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    print(out.stdout)
    return render(request, 'proto/index.html', {'data1': out.stdout})

The error

  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DotsPrototype'
b''
.
.
.
/external/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: What is your Script. Did you defined routes and business logic?

Comment: What in particular does not work? You have to call a view function after clicking the button to initialize the backend logic.

Comment: @Jonas- It seems to get into the script but gives errors on the imports that i have made and says the connection is aborted.

Comment: @Jonas - I did define the routes. Just got to know about business logic though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view that will handle the POST request on button click. The view will have the logic to call your script. Not sure if you creating REST APIs or a monolithic application. In both the cases, the approach remains the same.

Comment: I did exactly that but it seems to get into the script and gives errors on the imports that i have made and says the connection is aborted

Comment: Can you provide us your view please. It is tough to solve a coding issue without code :p

Comment: @SyedMuhammadIbrahim It's tough to figure out the issue this way. It's better if you add your current code and the traceback of the error you are getting.

Comment: @Jonas I am happy to provide the code but there is very minimal information about the code being referred to in the question. No code in the question hence no code in the answer :P

Comment: @AtulMishra I was refering to the OP, ye^^ we can't help that way